# Where can I ask a question about frameworks?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently read about a new JavaScript framework that also has a native mobile development initiative.

The framework claims to perform faster due to architectural differences, and I would like to know more about this. What is a suitable Stack Exchange site to ask this type of question?

Comment: A new JavaScript framework? [You don't say](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)!

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know more about this.

That is not a question.

If you want to ask "Why does framework X have a better performnace than regular JavaScript"  (as a title; the body would better contain some research) it's probably [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) material. One could compare it to [What semantic features of Python (and other dynamic languages) contribute to its slowness?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/324053/173647)

Comment: I would like to ask something like `"Does the superior performance of build time javascript interpretation of javacsriptframework also result in better performance on the native mobile development side of the framework?"`. I assume it should go on `Software Engineering` - but the linked to duplicate answer mentions `software tools` as part of `Stack Overflow`.